# Node.js MySQL updating records

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, database

I am capturing data from an API, putting it in an array ***([arr1])*** and using node-mysql to query my DB and insert data to it.

This is **working fine** when pushing new records, as per the below:

```
    var arr1 = response.data.map(function(item) {
    return [item.employeeDetails.id, item.employeeDetails.personalDetails.firstName, item.employeeDetails.personalDetails.lastName, item.employeeDetails.personalDetails.emailAddress];
});

var query = connection.query('INSERT IGNORE INTO employees(pk_userId, firstName, lastName, emailAddress) VALUES ?', [arr1],
    function(error, results, fields) {
        if (error) console.log(error);
        else {
            console.log("Imported=");
        }
    });
```

I am trying to add a second query, to update changed records. I have been reading tutorials and docs, however am still having issues. The following is what I am trying after following instructions online:

```
var query2 = connection.query('UPDATE employees SET ? WHERE ?', [arr1],
    function(err, rows) {
        if (err)
            console.log("Error Updating ", err);
    });
```

So, I am using the same **[arr1]** array that I got from the API, however I am a bit lost on how to tell MySQL to look for records to update.

Any advise or direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should set placeholders '?' with comma seperated syntax.

```
var query2 = connection.query('UPDATE employees SET ? WHERE ?', [var1, var2],
    function(err, rows) {
        if (err)
            console.log("Error Updating ", err);
    });
```

This will put var1 into first '?' and var2 into second'?'.

Comment: [arg1] is already separated by comma's. It's defined above as a variable.